# why does unity oncollisionenter2d not work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cant figure out why but whatever I try my bullet will not destroy when colliding with an object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class destroybullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

maybe I need to make the object like a box collider or something so i am open to suggestions

Comment: The first thing to check is that you are actually using 2D colliders, not 3D ones

Comment: And its not set to trigger

Comment: And character has rigidbody2D